# Is there a 'catalogue' of Euclid's use of Greek prepositions in his Elements?

Tags: ancient-greek

[A question on SE-Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/69040/21426) quoted Bullinger's *Companion Bible* referring to Euclid in order to define the meaning of εις in a metaphoric context.

> Euclid uses *eis* when a line is drawn to meet another line, at a certain point. Hence it denotes motion to or unto an object, with the purpose of reaching or touching it.

This reference was useful in that particular instance as it gave insight into the concept being analyzed.

Is there a definitive work which catalogues the use of Greek prepositions in Euclid's Elements such that we could use this as a reference work to gauge the spectrum of individual prepositional meanings and the overlap of concept between associated prepositions in the (Hellenistic/Koine) Greek language ?

Comment: I fail to see what Euclid has to do with any of this. If you want an overview of the usage of eis in early Christian-era texts the best place to look is Bauer & al., in their dictionary of  New Testament and Patristic Greek.

Comment: @fdb Greek grammars always contain a geometric diagram of a cube with arrows going in and out of it, in order to assist students to understand how Greek prepositions work. I am trying to find out if Euclid did the same (tangentially) by providing us with a valuable insight in his book _Elements_. I am aware of other references and I personally use Daniel B Wallace's _Beyond the Basics_.  But I am researching Euclid as well.